# How to serial.print data from another msp430 once subscribed to topic?

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe, msp430

I am publishing data with one msp430f5229 and I am trying to serial.print the data I am receiving from the publishing msp to the subscribing msp.

I have tried various print methods but I do not know how to extract the data from the subscriber once it is connected. I have commented the parts I believe is only necessary for publishing within the loop.

```
PubSubClient client(server, 1883, callback, wclient);

void callback(char* ScannerOut, byte* payload, unsigned int length){
    // Handle callback here
}

void setup()
{
    //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("Start WiFi");
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PWD);
    while(WiFi.localIP() == INADDR_NONE) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(300);
    }
    Serial.println("");

    printWifiStatus();

}

void loop()
{
    // read the input on analog pin:
    **//int sensorValue = analogRead(24);
    **//Serial.println(sensorValue);

    // convert into to char array
    **//String str = (String)sensorValue; 
    **//int str_len = str.length() + 1;  // Length (with one extra character 
    **//for the null terminator)
    **//char char_array[str_len];  // Prepare the character array (the buffer) 
    **//str.toCharArray(char_array, str_len);  // Copy it over 

    // publish data to MQTT broker
    if (client.connect("LaunchPadClient")) {
        **//client.publish("ScannerOut", char_array);
        client.subscribe("ScannerOut");
        Serial.println("Subscription successful!");

        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I am connecting and subscribing to the same topic as the msp publishing but I want to serial.print the output from that topic on my second msp.

Comment: you should format your code a bit better for easier readability

Comment: Maybe slightly better now

Comment: did a little fix.. Use ``` before and after code section.

Comment: Thank you. I am not very good at this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A subscriber receives its data through `void callback()` that is called usually inside something like `client.read()` function.

So your callback() may look like

```
void callback(char* ScannerOut, byte* payload, unsigned int length){
    Serial.print("%s", payload);
}
```

`client.read()` is missing in your loop. Please read your MQTT client documentation carefully about how the messages from broker are received.

Another point, don't disconnect from the broker right after `client.subscribe("ScannerOut");`.